# Access Denied when calling mc_login()

Tags: c#, soap, mantis

I stumbled upon MantisBT recently and got it set up at my workplace for future bug tracking. I wanted to make a neat little library we can use in our applications so that users can report bugs to us directly from the application in question.

Currently in a sandbox application I made to try and understand MantisConnect. I consumed the webservice successfully and I can make a client. But if I try and do this:

```
MantisConnectPortTypeClient client = new MantisConnectPortTypeClient();
UserData usrData = client.mc_login("omitted", "omitted");
```

I get a `FaultException` and the message "Access Denied"

[image]

Currently running Mantis 1.3.rc-dev.02

Any ideas on why this simple call is denied? It doesn't matter what user I use. It gets denied regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.

The WSDL file on the server was still pointing to mantisbt.org instead of our local server. Changed it to our local server address and it worked fine.

Comment: Could you please tell which file you have added the entries? I am facing similar issues with mc_login api